# bash, remove only half whitespaces from start of line

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I need remove whitespaces from start of line, but only 1/2, for example:

```
    <div class="section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>04</h4>
```

to

```
  <div class="section" id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4>04</h4>
```

etc.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: Just removed all whitespaces, but i don't know how to set it for half: sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'

Comment: What's your thought, and what have you tried? tip: replace two places with one place...

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? Pretty-print a html file?

Comment: Yes, I need intend 2 whitespaces instead 4 for every line (for example when I have 8 whitspaces, I need 4, when I have 12 whitespaces, I need 6, etc. Pretty-print html.

Comment: I'd use a tool like [Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/) to pretty-print HTML.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. But is possible to do it in bash, for example with sed or awk? Thank you.

Comment: This may work: `< input unexpand -t 2 | expand -t 1`, but it may also shorten non-leading whitespace.

Comment: It looks like you want to use `4` and `2` as arguments, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using group in sed

```
sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]\{1,\}\)\1/\1/' YourFile
```

you can use a white space instead of `[[:blank:]]` if you are sure it's space and not tab.

it do: replace a group of space  by this group if it appear twice at the begining, so this is half the full group of space

Comment: That renders undesirable indentation for me if he mixes TABs and spaces.

Comment: it's already the case because indentation with tab depend of editor settings. If needed (not the case in the request). It should define the tab equivalence and way wanted to replace it (ex: 3 space + tab + 5 space = ?)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need! There are only whitespaces, no tabs, so it is working well.

Comment: If there are a mix of spaces/tabs, then the source file should be passed through `expand` first.

Comment: I would suggest changing `*` to `\+` so that, for lines with no leading whitespace, sed does not have to replace the leading empty string with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Perl

```
perl -pe  's!(^\s+)!$x=length($1)/2;" " x $x!sme ' input_file
```

with your given inputs

```
$ cat stanislav.txt
    <div class="section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h4>04</h4>

$ perl -pe  's!(^\s+)!$x=length($1)/2;" " x $x!sme ' stanislav.txt
  <div class="section" id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4>04</h4>

$
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming all your leading white space is blank chars:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/^ */){$0=sprintf("%*s%s", int(RLENGTH/2), "", substr($0,RLENGTH+1))} 1' file
  <div class="section" id="contact">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h4>04</h4>
```

If not then run your file through `pr -e -t` first to make it so.